# is there a discrete version of Dambis Dubins Schwarz Theorem

Tags: pr.probability, martingales

> Theorem (Dambis, Dubins-Schwarz). If $M$ is a $\left(\mathscr{F}_t, P\right)$-continuous martingale vanishing at 0 and such that $\langle M, M\rangle_{\infty}=\infty$ and if we set
> $$
> T_t=\inf \left\{s:\langle M, M\rangle_s>t\right\},
> $$
> then, $B_t=M_{T_t}$ is a $\left(\mathscr{T}_{T_t}\right)$-Brownian motion and $M_t=B_{\langle M, M\rangle_t}$.

Here is the Dambis Dubins Schwarz theorem. I am wondering if it holds when M becomes discrete martingale?

Comment: What do you mean by "a discrete version of this theorem"? What do you mean by "it" in your "does it hold for discrete martingale?"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Does it also hold when M becomes a discrete martingale?

Comment: The answer is yes, with the cost that your filtration is large enough. By https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159496/can-every-discrete-martingale-be-embedded-in-a-continuous-martingale every discrete martingale can be embedded into a continuous one

Comment: @Fawen90 That answers my question, thanks!