# Can we construct close discrete martingales if their terminal marginal laws are close?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

As no answer or comment to [Can we construct close martingales if their terminal marginal laws are close?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460853/can-we-construct-close-martingales-if-their-terminal-marginal-laws-are-close) we consider a simplified version (discrete-time) as below:

Let $M=(M_k)_{0\le k\le n}$ be a real-valued martingale. Let $\mu := {\rm Law}(M_n)$ and $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. For any $\nu$ satisfying $W_2(\mu,\nu)\le \varepsilon$, can we construct two discrete-time martingales $X, Y$ (on suitable probability space) such that

$${\rm Law}(X)={\rm Law}(M),\quad {\rm Law}(Y_n)=\nu,\quad \mathbb E\big[\sup_{0\le k\le n}|X_k-Y_k|^2\big]\le 8\varepsilon^2?$$

Here $\mu,\nu$ are assumed to have finite second order moment, and $W_2$ denotes the Wasserstein distance of order $2$.

Comment: If continuity is no longer an issue since we are discrete time, what goes wrong with the method in the answer to your original post?

Comment: @NateRiver Do you mind specifying the details?

Comment: I mean, the details are given in the answer, just replace the time index with the non negative integers instead of $\mathbb R_+$.

Comment: @NateRiver I see the idea. What I wish to make rigorous is that, if your construct such $X,Y$, you need to find a common filtration for which both $X,Y$ are martingales. Of course from your construction, we need additional randomness that is not generated by the natural filtration of $X$...

Comment: Hm, it will suffice then to construct a $\mathcal F_1$-measurable random variable $Y_1$, then conditioning $Y_1$ on the natural filtration of $X$ gives us a martingale. But the optimal coupling forces extra randomness, which is a problem.