# Can any right-continuous martingale be approximated by continuous ones?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

It is known that any function that is right-continuous with left limits (càdlàg as a French abbreviation) can be approximated by continuous ones (under e.g. Skorokhod topology). Let $M=(M_t:0\le t\le T)$ be a càdlàg martingale (with as high integrability as you wish). My questions are as follows :

1. Can we construct a sequence of continuous martingales $M^n=(M^n_t:0\le t\le T)$ (that can be defined in different probability spaces) such that ${\rm Law}(M^n)\to {\rm Law}(M)$? Here $\to$ denotes the weak convergence of probability measures with respect to the Skorokhod topology.
2. Can we ensure further ${\rm Law}(M^n_T)={\rm Law}(M_T)$ for $n$ large enough?

Comment: In normal English, "Can any càdlàg martingale be approximated by..." can reasonably be construed as meaning "Is there any càdlàg martingale be approximated by...", so that in that context "any" becomes an existential quantifier rather than a universal quantifier. The three contexts in which that happens are (1) questions, (2) conditionals ("If any càdlàg martingale...), (3) negations ("There isn't any money left."). If "every" was meant", then writing "every" instead of "any" would be clear and unambiguous. English-speaking mathematicians use the word "any" too much.

Comment: It seems to me that with a  filtration that only changes at time T/2 all continuous martingales are constant.

Comment: @mike I believe this is not a counter example. For this case, we pick a martingale $M^n$ that is constant on $[0,T/2-1/n]$ and then constant on $[T/2,T]$. So $M^n$ is indeed a discrete-time martingale, and we use the result https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159496/can-every-discrete-martingale-be-embedded-in-a-continuous-martingale to embed this discrete martingale into a continuous one. With this construction we may ensure the approximation

Comment: @michaelhardy  Being french, I am surely not an expert in english language, but it is difficult for me to consider that "càdlàg" that is not even a word in french language, but a contraction for"continue à droite et limite à gauche" , could be a word in english language

Comment: @GérardLang and MichaelHardy Thanks for pointing out this confusing notation. I'm not French but I've been in France since 2009. According to my experiences càdlàg is commonly accepted in probability community in France, even in a lot of published English books, and in a lot of lecture notes. Anyway, I made some edits since both of you believe it's not reasonable...

Answer (score 2):

(Follow-up to OP's comment)

Good point.

If the laws converge then by a theorem of Skorokhod there is a probability space on which are defined càdlàg processes $\tilde M^n$ and $\tilde M$ such that $\tilde M^n$ has the same law as $M^n$, $\tilde M$ has th same law as $M$, and $\tilde M^n$ converges to $M$ a.s. (with respect to a suitable metric on the spaces of càdlàg paths). If we are using the Skorokhod $J_1$ topology on càdlàg paths, and if $\tilde M(\omega)$ has a jump at some time $t$, then the approximating path $\tilde M^n(\omega)$ must admit a jump at some time $t_n$ with $\lim_n t_n=t$ and $\lim_n[\tilde M^n_{t_n}(\omega)-\tilde M^n_{t_n-}(\omega)]=[\tilde M_{t}(\omega)-\tilde M_{t-}(\omega)]$. In particular, in my example, any sequence of processes approximating $X$ in law must have at least one jump (for large $n$) a.s., if one's notion of "convergence" is the $J_1$ topology. So there is no continuous martingale approximation available.

If you interpret convergence in the sense of the weaker $M_1$ topology on the space of càdlàg paths, then you can approximate a single-jump path of the type in my example by path continuous paths. But I doubt that the approximation can be accomplished with continuous martingales. Even with the more forgiving $M_1$ convergence, a continuous martingale close to $X_t$ should resemble (approximately) a time-changed Brownian motion.

Comment: Thank you very kindly for the further consideration. I find more details on  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.16026.pdf and I think your point is that, to approximate the limit with a jump of size $1$, the approximating sequence must contain a jump of similar size? If I am right, could you please show this with more details?

Comment: More precisely, can you prove, using the definition of the Skorokhod $J_1$ topology, "if $\tilde M(\omega)$ has a jump at some time $t$, then the approximating path $\tilde M^n(\omega)$ must admit a jump at some time $t_n$"?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be a unit-mean exponential random variable defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$. Let $\mathcal F_t:=\sigma\{T\wedge t\}$, $t\ge 0$. The filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0}$  is the smallest filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$ making $T$ a stopping time. The process $X_t:=1_{\{T\le t\}} -(t\wedge T)$ is a (non-continuous) $(\mathcal F_t)$-martingale. In fact, any càdlàg martingale $M_t$ in this situation takes the form $M_t=c+g(T)1_{\{T\le t\}} -\int _0^{t\wedge T} g(u)\,du$ for a constant $c\in\Bbb R$ and a Borel function $g:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ such that $\int_0^t |g(u)|\,du<\infty$ for each $t>0$. Crucially, the only continuous martigales are (deterministic) constant processes. This example shows that neither of your questions has an affirmative answer.

A more elaborate example would be the filtration generated by a unit-rate Poisson process. Again, the only continuous martingales are trivial.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very tricky example. Nevertheless, this does not correspond to my question I believe. Even not specified explicitly, what I pursue here is the law approximation. In other words, $M$ and $M^n$ can be defined in completely different probability spaces (and thus with different filtrations)

Comment: I don't say explicitly that $M^n$ and $M$ could live in different probability spaces, while I use the term $Law(M^n)\to Law(M)$, which means implicitly that $M^n$ can be in an alternative probability space. Edits have been made